# Find Gal (F/Q) where F= Q(sixth root of 2)

Tags: galois-theory

Find $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q})$, where $F= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2})$.

The possible $\mathbb{Q}$ automorphisms are $2^{1/6}$ and $-2^{1/6}$ and hence:

$θ_1$: $2^{1/6}$ maps to $2^{1/6}$

$θ_2$: $2^{1/6}$ maps to $-2^{1/6}$

Is this correct?

Comment: First, it would be nice to use TeX to format your question to make it more readable. Then, what do you mean by "the automorphisms are 2^1/6 and -2^1/6" ? Those are not automorphisms, but elements.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\theta\in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{6}}), \mathbb{Q})$. Then $\theta(2^{\frac{1}{6}})^6=\theta(2)=2$. Hence $\theta(2^{\frac{1}{6}})$ is a solution of the equation $x^6-2$.

So one way of figuring out the solution is to find all those solutions and to notice that a automorphism $\theta$ is completely determined by its value on $2^{\frac{1}{6}}$. Once you've done that you have to figure out which ones are actually automorphisms.